# 8051 interrupts(hardware) capability

Tags: interrupt, 8051

I have interfaced 8051 with an image sensor,the frame valid is connected to INT1,image sensor is capable of giving 60frames per second.that is 60 times frame valid interrupt per second,is 8051 is capable of handling 60 interrupts per second?
correct me if i am wrong.

regards,
geetha.

Comment: The real bottleneck is **how much code you place in your interrupt**. If you cadence it correctly, an 8051 is perfectly capable of handling 60 _small/medium_ interrupts per second. In fact, I use an 8051 for data acquisition (interrupt driven) at frequency up to 1kHz on 10 channels (so I acquire 10,000x16bits samples per second). However, at that speed I only record the sampled value and move on to the next, I wouldn't have time for much processing/calculations in between, or the interrupts would start to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

8051 based MCUs come in many shapes and forms. Most of modern ones have a much more efficient execution performance. The original ran at 12 cycles per instruction as far as I remember(don’t recall the isr to first instruction though.). That being said even the original ones are capable of 60 iterrupts per second. The real question though is how much processing you need to actually transfer each frame and how this will be implemented in your MCU(dma etc).